# Replacing a substring in a string with another substring in c using array of pointers to string

Tags: c, string

I am trying to replace a substring inside a string with another substring. However, I am getting a segmentation fault at line strcpy(p, str2); I do not understand why.
Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char *str[] = {"We will teach you how to",
        "Move a mountain",
        "Level a building",
        "Erase the past",
        "Make a million",
        "...all through C"
    };
    char str1[20], str2[20];
    printf("Enter first string\n");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    printf("Enter second string\n");
    scanf("%s", str2);
    char *news, *t, *p;
    int i;
    if(strlen(str2) > strlen(str1))
    {
        printf("Second string should be smaller than first string\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        p = strstr(str[i], str1);
        if(p)
        {
            news = p + strlen(str1);
            strcpy(t,news);
            strcpy(p, s);
            strcat(p,t);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("the new string is\n");
    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty to properly indent your code in order to make it more easy on the eyes. Please try to do so yourself in the future.

Comment: what is `t` pointer pointing to? Look at `strcpy(t, news);` is there memory allocated?

Comment: Did this code compile at all?

Comment: @vinay this question warrants a -1 from me. **protip** Ensure your code *compiles cleanly* as posted here and learn to use valgrind.

Comment: @t0mm13b or mcheck, or mtrace, or common sense, or, or ...

Answer (score 2):

You're copying to the string `t`, but you've never initialized it to point anywhere.

```
strcpy(t, news);
```

This is bad news — oh, no, it's bad `t` and good news.

You have a second problem, too.  You're trying to modify the strings in the `str` array of pointers, but those are string literals.  You can't modify string literals reliably.  You'll have to modify things so that you don't do that.

```
p = strstr(str[i], str1);  // Generates a pointer into str[i]
...
strcpy(p, s);    // Modifies str[i] -- unsuccessfully
```

Probably the easiest (but not necessarily best) fix for this is to use:

```
char str[][64] = {"We will teach you how to",
    "Move a mountain",
    "Level a building",
    "Erase the past",
    "Make a million",
    "...all through C"
};
```

I've not spent a long time cogitating on the correct size for the second dimension of the array, but 64 looks like it probably leaves enough space for you to grow the strings a bit.  Maybe that doesn't matter since there's a comment about the second string must be shorter than the first, so you're only dealing with shrinking strings.  Lucky you to be able to do that.  You'd have to be careful to avoid troubles if your strings can grow.

As first noted by [t0mm13b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206367/t0mm13b) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271739/replacing-a-substring-in-a-string-with-another-substring-in-c-using-array-of-poi/21271882#comment32051626_21271882), there's no variable `s` in the code.  Please make sure you post compilable code.

Looking further at that inner loop, we can see all sorts of problems:

1. The `news = p + strlen(str1);` assignment means that `news` is pointing to tail of `str[i]` after the `str1` was found in `str[i]`.
2. You copy an indeterminate amount of information from `news` into the space pointed at by an uninitialized pointer, `t`. This is a first source of core dump.
3. You copy the undefined variable `s` over `p`.  Is that meant to be `str2`, since `str2` is not used after the length check? This is a second source of core dump.
4. You copy the material from `t` after the material copied from `s`. If you've not already dumped core, this could be a third source of core dump (though maybe if you've not dumped core yet, this won't trigger one either).

You probably need:

```
char *p = strstr(str[i], str1);
if (p != 0)
{
    char t[64];
    strcpy(t, p + strlen(str1));
    strcpy(p, str2);
    strcat(p, t);
}
```

This is far from being proof from overflows, but is more nearly sound.

Comment: There's no variable `s` - just noticed that now... @vinay please double check your code for those teeny things, funny OP you never said it failed to compile?

Comment: Would not be surprised if that code was copy pasta from elsewhere and then decided to post here... and yeah that `strcpy(t, news);` is the source of the segfault alright - no surprises there...

Comment: My previous 'Urgh' comment was not entirely accurate.  Still, there's a presumption that the posted code will compile.  See the analysis - if you can be bothered, and I'd not blame you if you can't be bothered.

Comment: I have read your analysis and its absolutely spot-on! +1. If only, if, SO actually puts it back on the OP to say "Yo, does this code compile cleanly?", please verify before submitting question.. at this point, am not sure if the OP actually understands the code hence my comment about copy pasta....